# Polling freezes, Pebble.js, ajax, node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, pebble-watch, pebble-js

I am new to Pebble. Recently I wrote a simple program for the pebble client to get data from the server by polling.
I use Pebble.js, ajax and setInterval function. The server is on node.js.
The problem I have is that the polling freezes after 20+ queries, with no changes on the pebble but can still get query signal on the server.

Code on the client end in here, and the code on the server end is a simple http response.

```
var UI = require('ui');


var card = new UI.Card({
title: 'Pebble.js',
body: 'Press any button.'
});

card.show();

var ajax = require('ajax');

setInterval(function(){ 
ajax({ url: 'http://182.92.151.205:20000/quote', type: 'json' },
function(data) {
card.body(data.quote);
card.title(data.author);
},
function(error){
card.body(error);
card.title('no');
}
);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself, reason: no gc when using ajax!

Comment: What do you mean no gc? How did you solve the problem?